# How to make use of neon coprocessor with openssl?

Tags: compilation, openssl, arm, neon

I am using TI Sitara processor am335x. To increase the cryptographic performance I want to make use of neon coprocessor. Should I compile both openssl library and my application for neon or just the library? Any other procedure to do for making use of neon?

These are the flags I passed to the Configure script of openssl while building the library and I din't get the expected output.

```
-O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to upgrade to 1.0.2, which has improved NEON support.